# Simulating 32 bit processor register - Compiler enough or 32 bit OS required?

Tags: gcc, operating-system, 32-bit, processor

I have an assignment to make some assembly code that I am supposed to run on a intel processor with a 32 bit register. The problem is that I don't have a 32 bit processor.

**My question: I am wondering if compiling as 32-bit application with -m32 in gcc is enough to simulate 32-bit processor register? Or do I need to install a 32 bit OS to properly simulate a 32 bit processor register?**

Comment: you could fully emulate a modern 64bit OS running on an i7 cpu  using an ancient 8088-4.77mhz box as the host. performance may be somewhat lacking, but it is theoretically doable. so... yes, you can do 32bit math on a cpu that isn't itself 32bit. it just takes more instructions and won't be as efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "simulate a 32 bit register" a 64 bit register "simulates" a 32 bit register if you ignore the upper 32 bits.

Comment: Yeah, so I guess my question is basically if compiling in gcc as 32 bit application will make it ignore the upper 32 bits? Or do I need to run a 32-bit OS?

Comment: If you compile as a 32 bit application, it'll run on a 64 bit processor the same as if it were running on a 32 bit processor (assuming we're talking about x86/x86_64).